# Firebase CRUD, issues with update and delete

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with firebase so I tried creating a simple CRUD function where I'm only able to do the saving of data. I will not be using the newPostKey method because there's only one user on this website. I would like to update the user_name and delete the entire data using the plate_no value but my code is not working. Here's my code:

```
    function save_user() {
        var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
        var plate_no = document.getElementById('plate_no').value;

        var data = {
            user_name: user_name
        }

        var updates = {};
        updates['/users/' + plate_no] = data;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

        alert('The User is Created Successfully!');
        reload_page();
    }

    function update_user() {
        var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
        var plate_no = document.getElementById('plate_no').value;

        var data = {
            user_id: plate_no,
            user_name: user_name
        }

        var updates = {};
        updates['/users/' + plate_no] = data;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

        alert('The User is Updated Successfully!');
        reload_page();
    }

    function delete_user() {
        var user_id = document.getElementById('plate_no').value;

        firebase.database().ref().child('/users/' + plate_no).remove();
        alert('The User is Deleted Successfully!');
        reload_page();
    }

    function reload_page() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: update() and remove() return a Promise, use a callback or then() so you can show the alert() after the action is done.

Answer (score 0):

update() and remove() returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), use a callback or then() so you can show the alert() after the action is confirmed done.

or better, use .catch() to get the errors and see why it´s not working. 
ie:

```js
firebase.database().ref().child('/users/' + plate_no).remove()
   .then(() => { 
       console.log('success!, show alert now'); 
   }) 
   .catch(err => { 
       console.log('errorcode', err.code); 
   });
```